# Bootstrap 4 Card - Shorter border above footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using **Bootstrap 4**, is there a way to decrease the length of the top border of the `card-footer`?

The normal `card-footer` border spans the entire width of the card.
I tried using the margin utils (mx-3) on the `card-footer` to shorten the visible border...

```
        <div class="card">
             <div class="card-body">
                  ..
             </div>
             <div class="card-footer mx-3">
                  Footer
             </div>
        </div>
```

However, with the added margin, the footer content doesn't line up with the `card-body` content...

[image]

Is there a way to shorted the visible border AND have the Card footer aligned with the body using ***only the Bootstrap 4 classes***, and no extra CSS?

[Codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/WRFHtxx30D)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this problem can be solved using the [spacing utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/).

In Bootstrap 4, the `.card-body` and `.card-footer` both have side padding.

By instead *adding* padding to the parent `.card` (`px-3`), and *removing* the padding (`px-0`) from the `.card-body` and `.card-footer` (so that they counteract each other) the visible top border of the footer is then decreased. The body and footer content align on the left side.

https://www.codeply.com/go/fSLiGhbNWV

```
<div class="card px-3">
     <div class="card-body px-0">
          Content
     </div>
     <div class="card-footer text-muted bg-transparent px-0">
          Footer
     </div>
</div>
```

This demonstrates how useful the utility classes.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but found that simply adding  px-0 to the .card class fixed it. It also fixed the issue with any card images rendering too small

Comment: I don't think this works. The card in Bootstrap 4 has no padding in the first place. Only the card-body and card-footer have padding. And, this would not put the desired spacing next to the border.